# How to look up URL names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can you use Javascript to parse out the URL of a page?

Comment: Do you want to edit the XML with JavaScript? Can you use XPath?

Comment: If you edit everything by hand, why do you ask for a program?

Comment: I have written a large XML file that stores the portions of the site that will be different from site to site, using a general template as the base.  The way it is now, each site has to be manually updated in the HTML (50+ sites) so my end goal here is to be able to have a large XML file that stores the information of each site that will be different on a site by site basis as shown in my XML in the question.  Going into 1 XML file and editing portions of a site is much easier than loading up 50 sites individually and changing them in the HTML.

Comment: Why do you put a volatile information like the status of the network into a file that you manually edit by hand? Or maybe your comments don't match your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this:

```
<script>
   function mySiteURL() {
    var myURL = window.location.href;
    var dashIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf("-");
    var dotIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf(".");
    var result = myURL.substring(dashIndex + 1, dotIndex);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to decide whether you want to do this on the client or on the server. On the server, you can load the XML and use XPath to locate the part of the XML DOM tree that contains the site:

```
//site/name[text() = 'Blah00']
```

When using JavaScript on the client, a better solution would be to have a server which keeps the current status per site (use a database or some in-memory structure). Then use AJAX requests to ask the server for the information for a certain site. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will make your life much easier.